# Word 2013 RTM Javascript API compatibility

Tags: xml, ms-word, office-js

When trying to sideload a taskpane add-in (Javascript API for Office) manifest in Word 2013 RTM (15.0.4420.1017), the add-in does not show up in the shared folder app catalog.

The shared folder shows the message "No apps currently available.". When sideloading it into Word 2013 SP1 consumer (15.0.5015.1000), it does show up in the trusted folder app catalog.

Is Word 2013 RTM compatible with the Javascript API for Office? If not, what is the minimum required version for an app based on the Javascript API for Office to work? If it is compatible, what could be the cause of the app not showing up?

Below are screenshots, first of the working system, then of the system where it doesn't load:

[Working environment, 15.0.5015.1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDRs7.png)

[Not working environment, 15.0.4420.1017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz3q4.png)

I know for sure that the XML manifest is valid, it's been validated and on one of the system the app actually works. Also the setup on both systems is done the same way (by sharing a folder with myself to get a network location, adding it to the catalog and restarting word).

Also screenshots of the versions, first of the working system, then of the system where it doesn't load:

[Working environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRuZN.png)

[Not working environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVpj5.png)

Below a copy of the manifest I've been using, with relevant information edited. On my other machine localhost is obviously replaced by my external IP, and the ports are properly forwarded (I can access the server in Chrome).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
    <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
    <Id>23639468-3a3d-4875-ac5e-b1c5e4778d28</Id>
    <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Author</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Displayname"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
    <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/support " />
    <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
    <!--<SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]">-->
    <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <!--End Basic Settings. -->
    <!--Begin TaskPane Mode integration. This section is used if there are no VersionOverrides or if the Office client version does not support add-in commands. -->
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Document" />
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <!-- End TaskPane Mode integration.  -->
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    <!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
    <VersionOverrides 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
        <Hosts>
            <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
            <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
            <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
            <Host xsi:type="Document">
                <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
                    <GetStarted>
                        <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                        <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>
                        <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                        <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>
                        <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
                    </GetStarted>
                    <!-- Function file is a HTML page that includes the JavaScript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called.
                Think of the FunctionFile as the code behind ExecuteFunction. -->
                    <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />
                    <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
                        <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
                        <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
                            <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
                            <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                                <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                                <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
                                <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                                        <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                        <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                                        <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                                        <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                                        <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <!-- You can use resources across hosts and form factors. -->
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png" />
                <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
                <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <!-- ShortStrings max characters==125. -->
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <!-- LongStrings max characters==250. -->
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
    <!-- End Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
</OfficeApp>
```

I've also tried changing  `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"` to `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0"`

Comment: Can you please add a copy of your manifest? (and remove all privacy info)  thanks!

Comment: Hi @JuanBalmori, I've added the copy to the original post!

Comment: thanks, we are reviewing this.

Comment: @JuanBalmori has your review had any results yet? I'm eager to know!

Answer (score 0):

Different builds of Office have different support for various APIs. In your manifest, seems you want to use commands (ribbon buttons) and support for those wasn't introduced until Office 2016. Specific build numbers for different APIs are documented on requirement sets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/office-versions-and-requirement-sets

If you need to create and add-in that works with Office 2013 RTM (there were very few APIs supported back then) you will need a manifest that can be understood by that version of Office. I don't have one around but a cursory review of your manifest signals things like the  node and the  node that I believe were not supported in RTM.

My recommendation would be to start with SP1 as the bare minimum.

Comment: I'm sure that that's not the issue. The 2016 features don't obstruct usage in the 2013 SP1 version of Word. Besides that, I've also used a XML with the bare minimum of content, which did not load either.

What my question is, is if using the add-in with RTM should be possible in the first place or not, since it is stated the API is supported in 2013, not SP1 specifically to my knowledge.